# Contructor is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

my error is:

> Error 1   'aCI.CheckTexture.CheckTexture()' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

and i use this code to check some files MD5/Hash :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace aCI
{
class CheckTexture
{   
    Thread Search;
    protected CheckTexture()
    {
        Search = new Thread(Scan);
        Search.Start();
    }

    protected void Scan()
    {
        if (GetMD5Hash("1.rar") != "9647997C556C5A37A63EFAFBCA4A40D0"
           || GetMD5Hash("2.rar") != "6626959A9099B4C6F5C755E0D2E57EF8"
           || GetMD5Hash("3.rar") != "4D6611A825F81024E0153E2753B8A27E")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
            "Sorry come back and restor your orginal files.",
            "Error",
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }

    #region Hash Calculator

    private static byte[] ConvertStringToByteArray(string data)
    {
        return (new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()).GetBytes(data);
    }

    private static System.IO.FileStream GetFileStream(string pathName)
    {
        return (new System.IO.FileStream(pathName, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
             System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite));
    }

    public static string GetSHA1Hash(string pathName)
    {
        string strResult = "";
        string strHashData = "";

        byte[] arrbytHashValue;
        System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = null;

        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider oSHA1Hasher =
              new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        try
        {
            oFileStream = GetFileStream(pathName);
            arrbytHashValue = oSHA1Hasher.ComputeHash(oFileStream);
            oFileStream.Close();

            strHashData = System.BitConverter.ToString(arrbytHashValue);
            strHashData = strHashData.Replace("-", "");
            strResult = strHashData;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!",
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error,
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

        return (strResult);
    }

    public static string GetMD5Hash(string pathName)
    {
        string strResult = "";
        string strHashData = "";

        byte[] arrbytHashValue;
        System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = null;

        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider oMD5Hasher =
              new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        try
        {
            oFileStream = GetFileStream(pathName);
            arrbytHashValue = oMD5Hasher.ComputeHash(oFileStream);
            oFileStream.Close();

            strHashData = System.BitConverter.ToString(arrbytHashValue);
            strHashData = strHashData.Replace("-", "");
            strResult = strHashData;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!",
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error,
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

        return (strResult);
    }
    #endregion
  }

}
```

Then i try Using class CheckTexture from the above code in here:

```
 private void BtnMpLanClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists("chrome.exe"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find chrome.exe");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            //Process.Start("chrome.exe");
            this.StartTheProcess("chrome.exe", "");

            Thread.Sleep(10);

            try
            {
                // I have error on this line:

                CheckTexture Scan = new CheckTexture();

            }
            catch (Exception)

            { }

        }

    }
```

but I have that error on this line:

```
CheckTexture Scan = new CheckTexture();
```

SO pleas if possible someone tel me what is my mistake.
Thank you for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class isn't public. Change it to:

```
public class CheckTexture
{   
    Thread Search;
    public CheckTexture()
    {
        Search = new Thread(Scan);
        Search.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Note that the constructor is protected as well. Might not be resolved by just changing the accessor on the class.

Comment: sorry but also have same problem!!

Comment: As carameiriel says, the constructor will need to be public as well. (See my edit)

Answer (score 5):

In C#, default access modifier of classes is [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).

So your `CheckTexture` class is `internal`. Change it to [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) like;

```
public class CheckTexture
{
 ...   
}
```

From [`Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
>   be either public or internal. **Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.**

But this doesn't enough. Because when you write;

```
CheckTexture Scan = new CheckTexture();
```

This calls parameterless constructor of `CheckTexture` class which its access modifier is [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx). Make it `public` also.

```
public CheckTexture()
{
    Search = new Thread(Scan);
    Search.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

by default the class in C# is `internal`. Mark it `public`. Based on @Caramiriel comment, the constructor also needs to be marked `public`